# git reset to remove multiple merge pull requests on master branch

Tags: git, reset, pull-request

I have a git repo with two branches, dev and master. I've been developing on dev, then I did a pull request to merge dev back into master, then I did a release. Then, I add a few more commits on dev, then I did another pull request. Now I am regretting that I didn't just wait a bit to do ONE pull request instead of multiple for the release. I am thinking to `git reset` to the point on master just before I did that first pull request and commit and push so as to get rid of the subsequent merges, so I can redo just ONE pull request. Please see below diagram for my situation on master:

`A - merge_pullreqest1 - merge_pullreqest2`

can I go on `master` and do the following: `git reset A`, then `git commit -m "clean slate"`, then `git push`. Next, go to my `dev` branch and do a final pull request (that include all the changes in the merge_pullrequest1 and merge_pullrequest2). Would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **git reset --hard A** (to get history back from the branch and forget about the two merges), then you can merge the second pull request revision to get a single merge from dev. Then you will have to **git push --force** to the remote.

Comment: so BEFORE I do the final pull request from `dev`, I do the `git reset` on master, then I have to commit and push --force to get it to finalize on master first, right?

Comment: I think so. Just in case, this is git, it's very flexible. As long as you keep the IDs of revisions (or keep them to a private branch, just in case), you can get back to how things were before so don't be afraid to mess things up until you get it right.

Comment: I just tried this on a small repo and it seems to work, but having one issue, after reset the two previous merges on master, when I do a new pull request, it still labels it as merge #3, is there a way to have it reset the internal merge counter?

Comment: I don't think that counter is part of git, but I might be wrong. And if that's the case, I don't know how to reset it. If that's set up by bitbucket or github I don't know how to reset it either.